# Bazel & Tensorflow: Inception v3 retraining: AttributeError: 'int' object attribute '__doc__' is read-only

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, bazel, pre-trained-model

I am currently following this tutorial to retrain the top layer of the Inception v3 neural net:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2D02eZTB4s
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining

I have set up a VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS 64bit

python 2.7.6

tensorflow 1.3.0

bazel build label: 0.5.3

However, when I use the command

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain --image_dir /media/myImageDir
```

then my process diverges from the tutorial. Two import errors occur which are easily solved by installing the packages.

```
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 28, in <module>
    from autograd import core as ag_core
ImportError: No module named autograd

File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 24, in <module>
    import enum  # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
ImportError: No module named enum
```

After installing autograd and enum, when trying to execute the command to retrain again, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 108, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 102, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework.importer import import_graph_def
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 30, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.framework import function
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/framework/function.py", line 34, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.ops import variable_scope as vs
File "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 191, in <module>
"""
AttributeError: 'int' object attribute '__doc__' is read-only
```

Line 191 of the file "/home/tensorflow/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py" is as follows:

```
AUTO_REUSE.__doc__ = """
When passed in as the value for the `reuse` flag, AUTO_REUSE indicates that
get_variable() should create the requested variable if it doesn't exist or, if
it does exist, simply return it.
"""
```

Now I don't really want to meddle with this code as it is not custom code that I've written. I suspect there to be another problem, but I am absolutely clueless what it might be. I'm hoping someone here has had a similar problem and/or can give me any advice.

Comment: it seems you didn't install tensorflow correctly, the error comes up when you try to import tensorflow. Try reinstalling tensorflow

Comment: If I import tensorflow in the python interpreter, it works though

Answer (score 2):

I've just come across this too, and I noticed that there was an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12491) about this in tensorflow recently.  The solution is the following workaround:

- Uninstall enum, if you've already installed it: `sudo pip remove enum`
- Install this compatibility version of enum: `sudo apt-get install python-enum34`
- Try again.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by correcting the source code  brutally !!!